# Converting an existing 'Data' volume to APFS encrypted

Tags: macos, encryption, apfs, apple-silicon

Laptop: Macbook Pro M1
OS: macOS Ventura 13.1

I regularly work on sensitive data on my laptop and I want everything to be encrypted by default.

The best way to do that I imagine is to encrypt my existing Data volume using the Disk Utility program. However, it's currently using the default APFS (no encryption) and there seem to be no way to convert it to APFS (encrypted).

Is it just not possible, or am I simply missing it? If it's not possible, what are the alternative?

I prefer not to resort to creating an additional encrypted volume while leaving the Data volume unencrypted, as it is less elegant of a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not try to encrypt the startup APFS volumes using Disk Utility.

Instead Use System Settings > Privacy & Security > FileVault > Turn on.

This will encrypt the `Macintosh HD - Data` (or whatever it is called) volume.

The Apple Support page describes this: [Use FileVault to encrypt you Mac startup disk](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837).  Read what it says about how you will recover the disk if you forget your password - either via iCloud or a recovery key you write down (or store somewhere safe).

Comment: Minor nit-pic, with post T2 macs it already is encrypted. Turning on FileVault simply changes it to require your credentials rather than unlocking automatically - that’s why it doesn’t take hours to encrypt any more.